# Compiz cube not working with 12.04 in gnome classic or unity

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, compiz, workspaces

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 on my Dell Studio XPS (Specs at end of post) with nvidia-current installed as the proprietary drivers and I'm mainly using Gnome Classic but this issue does happen in Unity too.

According to the workspace switcher in the corner, I have 4 workspaces in a 2x2 format, when I click on another workspace it only switches between 2. Selecting workspace 3 on the launcher switches to 1 and 4 switches to 2. I have the compiz cube enabled and when rotating workspaces it is just a plane with a dekstop on each face rather than the cube.

If I go into the compiz settings and have a look at the number of workspaces, it only shows 1 and if I increase them to 4 the workspace switcher changes to a 4x1 arrangement and selecting any of the other 3 not just changes to that workspace but without a desktop environment or any windows (including conky). If it hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for terminal, it then jumps back to workspace 1 and opens a terminal.

I have been using my laptop with another monitor configured in twinview, but I have also tried disabling this and using one monitor and the issue still occurs.

In want to configure it to have 4 workspaces which display properly in the compiz cube and it would be nice to have this working across both monitors.

[It would be wonderful to have 4 workspaces for each monitor and a separate cube and switcher for each one giving 8 total but I think that's just greedy :p]

Laptop spec

```
i7-2630QM
12GB RAM
NVIDIA gefore 555M (3D display so optimus is disabled ignores the intel HD3000)
17" Screen 1920x1080
Second monitor acer p223w 1680x1050
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note that the switcher icon in the launcher will *always* show 2x2,** regardless of your actual workspace layout.

The Compiz Cube is designed to work only with *horizontal* one-dimensional workspace layouts, not the default 2x2 Ubuntu Unity layout; changing to a 1x4 (1 vertical, 4 horizontal) workspace layout should fix it.

To make that work:

- Open CCSM, go to General, and set the workspace layout to 1x4:

  [image]
- Now disable *Desktop Wall* and enable the *Desktop Cube* and *Rotate Cube* plugins.
- The default cube transition speed can be so fast that it looks like a plane. To adjust, you can tweak the *Additional Settings* in the *Rotate Cube* plugin
- After enabling all this, reboot!

**Here's a [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkjxX-4DSqw&feature=plcp) showing the cube fully functional with 4 workspaces on one monitor.** The applications are Firefox, Synaptic, Terminal and Software Center, one on each workspace.

Comment: I'm not using unity so the 'unity --reset' line was not needed but changing from a 2x2 to a 1x4 has done it. Can you please update your answer to reflect that. Then I will award you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu Tweak and use it to change the number of workspaces.

[image]